# How to use migration programmatically in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

So I want to use migrations in a programmatic way, for this I've done something like this.

Seed is an extension method which I've created over StoreContext

StoreContext is my DbContext

```
 internal StoreContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
            RelationalDatabaseCreator creator = this.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator;

            if (!creator.Exists())
            {
                creator.Create(); ///=> create database
                creator.CreateTables(); ///=> create database tables
            }

            Database.Migrate(); ///=> apply migrations

            if (creator.Exists())
            {
                this.Seed(); 
            }
        }
```

If the database does not exist the when I ran

> Add-Migration Initial

all is good (this is only for my first migration)

If I decide to add new migration

> Add-Migration Add_Student_FirstName

a new field in Student then I get this PMC exception

> There is already an object named 'SomeTableName' in the database.

the SomeTableName that the console complains about is not necessarily the table on which I've added the change.

But if i go into my code and comment the line for

```
 Database.Migrate(); ///=> apply migrations
```

and run again

> Add-Migration Add_Student_FirstName

all is good again (my migration is added to Migrations folder, but I still have to do the migration by hand using the

> Update-Database

command)

So what is wrong in what I'm doing, and how should I fix this so that the migration will be applied automatically when i create it ?

Thanks